# CORS error Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check - error only on POST but not GET? Hapi Node server Vue client

Tags: cors, hapi.js

I have a Hapi Node server and a Vue front end.

I've checked every duplicate and tried every suggestion I could find.

This same call used to work with an older Angular based client in Node 10. Now using Node 14 and Vue axios, I'm assuming this is the change that added this issue.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/getDownloadUrl'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I do NOT get this error on any of my GET calls, only on this one POST

I tried adding all the CORS options and configurations I could find online I keep getting the same error

On the server I tried all combination of configs, here is the most inclusive

```
server.connection({
  port: 3000,
  host: "localhost",
  routes: {
    cors: {
      origin: ["*"], // an array of origins or 'ignore'
      headers: [
        "Access-Control-Allow-*",
        "Authorization",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE",
      ], // an array of strings - 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'
      exposedHeaders: [
        "Access-Control-Allow-*",
        "Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE",
      ], // an array of exposed headers - 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers',
      additionalExposedHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-*", "Accept"], // an array of additional exposed headers
      credentials: true, // boolean - 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
    }
  }
})
```

Also tried adding the cors flag to the route itself

I also tried adding some headers client side though I don't think this is the actual issue, no help

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});
```

Here are screens of the error I'm getting, when using the simplified CORS settings that jub0bs recommended below

[image: console error]
[image: network tab info]

How can I tell everyone here that this POST should be allowed, which I guess is adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the resource? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? Cookie-based or token-based (e.g. `Authorization: Bearer xxx`)?

Comment: Please edit your question and add screenshots of the problematic request and response (with all their headers) from your browser's Network tab

Comment: @jub0bs added screenshots, thanks so much for helping out... I'm sure it's something silly I'm missing :-\

Comment: Those `Access-Control-Allow`... have nothing to do in a request; they're _response_ headers. Drop them from your request and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Where do I start?...

1. The [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) has no place in a request, as it is a *response* header. You can safely drop it from your Axios request.
2. Accordingly, listing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the `headers` property of your CORS configuration makes no sense. Drop it.
3. Although exposing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the client may be useful, you most likely do not need to do that. You should be able to safely drop it from the exposed `exposedHeaders` property of your CORS configuration.
4. Why would you list methods (`"GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"`) in the `headers` and `exposedHeaders` properties of your CORS configuration? That seems like a copy/paste error. Remove that. In fact, after closer inspection of [the source code](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/cors.js), I realised that Hapi's CORS middleware doesn't even allow you to configure which methods should be allowed and gives them all a free pass. Questionable design decision...
5. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by listing `Access-Control-Allow-*` as an allowed request header and as an exposed header... Hapi's CORS middleware [doesn't perform any kind of regex matching on headers](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/cors.js). At the very least, because all header names that start with `Access-Control-Allow-` are *response* headers, listing them in the `headers` property of your CORS configuration makes no sense.
6. Because your request contains a `Content-Type` header with value `application/json`, you need to explicitly allow that request header in your CORS configuration. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests
7. Do clients really need to access the response's `Accept` response header? Doubtful, since this is a *request* header. Drop that name from the `exposedHeaders` property. Similarly, you can likely drop the `additionalExposedHeaders` property.
8. Under the assumption that you use token-based authentication (as opposed to cookie-based authentication), you don't need to allow credentials. In fact, if you use cookie-based authentication, you're exposing your users to cross-origin attacks, because specifying `origin: ["*"]` together with `credentials: true` in your Hapi CORS configuration allows *all* origins without discrimination (i.e. including malicious ones) with credentials!

---

In the end, a functional and more dramatically more secure CORS configuration would be:

```js
cors: {
  origin: ["*"],
  headers: [
    "Authorization",
    "Content-Type",
  ],
}
```

Comment: thanks @jub0bs for the very detailed response - all of my settings in there were just blind attempts at getting things to work lol .... I tried your CORS settings and I'm still getting the same error though :( any other ideas?